# In Oracle SOA Suite 12c EM Console, How is the WSDL's URL path constructed in the composite's test page?

Tags: testing, wsdl, soa, bpel, suite

Oracle SOA Suite 12c. EM Console.

In the EM Console SOA Infrastructure -> Folder -> Composite -> Test button.
How is the WSDL's URL path constructed?  I mean, Where is it getting the http://hostname:port/ part of the URL?
We need to change it from http://hostname:80/ to https://hostname:443/ to prevent the error:
"Either the WSDL/WADL URL is invalid or the WSDL/WADL file is not valid or incorrect. - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"

[Incorrect WSDL URL Path]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG1HK.png)

Thank you.

The correct WSDL can be accessed by updating the text field with the URL.
But it takes ~5 minutes to show it, because it is looking for the Non-SSL address.